# How do I exclude all constructors from Visual Studio Code Coverage results?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I am creating a RunSettings file that will exclude all properties and constructors from the code coverage results in VS2012.  I am aware of the ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute, however I want to achieve this in the runsettings file using a regular expression.  My regular expressions for the get and set methods do work for removing the code coverage for properties, but its not working for constructors.

```
<Functions>
                        <Exclude>
                            <Function>^Fabrikam\.UnitTest\..*</Function>
                            <Function>^std::.*</Function>
                            <Function>^ATL::.*</Function>
                            <Function>.*::__GetTestMethodInfo.*</Function>
                            <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppCodeCoverageFramework::.*</Function>
                            <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::.*</Function>                             
                             <Function>.*\.ctor.*</Function>                                
                              <Function>.*\.set_.*</Function>
                              <Function>.*\.get_.*</Function>
                        </Exclude>
                    </Functions>
```

Comment: what about properties/constructors that do not have default implementations but actually have real code that should be tested/covered?

Comment: silly observation, but if the constructors aren't used, neither is the class - write some tests or delete the unused code

Comment: Yes if the constructors are doing any sort of logic I agree they should be tested, but sometimes there are a few different overloads that aren't really doing anything other than assignment.  I suppose one could argue those should be tested to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<Function>.*\.\.ctor.*</Function>
```

As the ctor already has a dot preceding it

Comment: I hadn't tried that but that didn't work either.  Maybe its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I got today to the same issue. After a bit playing with regex I came up with this:

```
<Function>.*(\.[^\.\(]*)\1\(.*</Function>
```

[or try here](https://regex101.com/r/fO0bQ6/1) the regex